# The genus of the following algebraic curve(tetragonal curve)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

$$\mathcal F(\lambda, y) =    {y}^{4}- \left( 2 {\lambda}^{8}+{\lambda}^{4}+2 \right) {y}^{3}+ \left( 2 {\lambda}^{16}+4 {\lambda}^{14}+3 {\lambda}^{12}  +4 {\lambda}^{2}+2 \right) {y}^{2} \\-4 {\lambda}^{2}\left(  {\lambda}^{20}+ {\lambda}^{16}+4 \right) y+{\lambda}^{4}(4 {\lambda}^{24}-3 {\lambda}^{20}+4 )=0$$
I am trying to construct the Riemann theta function solution of a soliton equation. The curve comes from the characteristic polynomial of the Lax pair of the soliton equation.

Noting that the curve is singular at the original point $(0, 0)$, I want to know if it is possible to make the curve a compact Riemann surface. If so, what is its genus, the local coordinates at the origin?

Comment: This is a very complicated definition for a curve—it's degree $4$ in $y$ and degree $28$ in $\lambda$, and has $15$ distinct terms. Why do you care about this curve, its genus, and the local coordinate of the original point? Some of that information, and anything you've attempted, may be helpful to people who might know how to approach a question like this

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I am trying to construct the Riemann theta function solution of a soliton equaiton. This curve  comes from the characteristic polynomial of the Lax pair of the soliton equation .@Jackson

Comment: [Crossposted at MO, with answer in comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385917/the-genus-of-the-following-algebraic-curvetetragonal-curve).